# How to prevent Thunderbird to download all emails after fresh install?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have installed Thunderbird on my Ubuntu machine and connected my gmail account and Thunderbird started to download all my emails (2353 emails)

How to prevent this from happening. I don't want to download all my mails. 
10 or 20 last mails is more than enough!

Is there some option to change this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Never used it but try this settings:

1. Open thunderbird
2. Click on the email account you wish to limit synchronization
3. Select `View Settings for this account` under Account section
4. In`Synchronization & Storage` look at `Disk Space` and select `Synchronize the most recent`. Choose a number of days.

[image]

Comment: I don't have this option. Probably it is available for IMAP accounts only, not for POP.

Comment: The option is under  Edit > Account settings > Synchronisation and Storage on the latest version.

Comment: It seems odd that the _default_ is to imediately download every email you've ever had?  That could easily be decades of emails and GBs of data before you realise what's going on (!).

Comment: Exactly that happened to me

Comment: Happened to me too, 23Gb then my ssd full and I arrive on this thread